# Disable spellchecking a specific orthography without turning off flycheck

Tags: flycheck, spell-checking

I frequently have buffers (Org-Mode, but that should be irrelevant) where I have a mix of Koine Greek, Ancient Hebrew, and English. I have spellchecking set up for Koine and English, but I have not found a `hunspell` dictionary for ancient Hebrew. As such `flycheck` thinks all Hebrew words are misspelled English words. The red squiggly underline makes most vowels impossible to see in pointed Hebrew. As such I end up turning of `flycheck` in these buffers, and misspelling my English and Greek words. If I could limit the blast radius by registering the Hebrew orthography with `flycheck` the way that I have registered the Greek, albeit not to spellcheck it but to ignore it, this would significantly improve the situation. Is there a tractable way to accomplish this?

In case it is relevant, here is what I have for the Greek:

```
  (add-to-list 'ispell-local-dictionary-alist
               '("ancient-greek"
                 "[θωερτψυιοπασδφγηςκλζξχβνμΘΩΕΡΤΨΥΙΟΟΠΑΣΔΦΓΗΚΛΖΞΧΒΝΜ]"
                 "[^θωερτψυιοπασδφγηςκλζξχβνμΘΩΕΡΤΨΥΙΟΟΠΑΣΔΦΓΗΚΛΖΞΧΒΝΜ]"
                 "᾿"
                 nil
                 ("-d" "grc_GR"); Dictionary file name
                 nil
                 utf-8))
```